# Devise - openid + ldap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, openid, ldap, devise

So, I've been studying about Devise and I've really liked it, but one thing I didn't understand is, can you use multiple providers (e.g. ldap login + facebook/google/etc.)? So, what I want is:

- User - information connected to my website
- Linked provides - so, I want Users to be able to link their accounts to multiple providers.

For example, let's say we have user example_user. It has its facebook, google and ldap account linked to its account, so if it tries to login in with ldap, google or facebook account, it'll succeed and give me its instance of model User.

Sorry for my bad language, I'm quite bad at explaining my issue.

Thanks!

EDIT: I've resolved it by using omniauth.

Comment: Hey Matija, if you have resolved it, answer your own question and accept your own answer. The community is dying to hear from you ;)

Comment: Honestly, didn't quite work on Active Directory, only openldap ... :(

Answer (score 1):

maybe these three pointers will help:

http://wiki.phys.ethz.ch/readme/devise_with_ldap_for_authentication_in_rails_3

http://random-rails.blogspot.com/2010/07/ldap-authentication-with-devise.html

http://vimeo.com/13105005

Comment: well, this was quite a while ago... so, I succeeded in making it work on openldap (using articles you mentioned in your answer), but it didn't quite work on active directory.

I don't currently have enough free time to take the gem and debug it, but I plan to in a week or two. :)

Comment: Active Directory's schema is messed up in many ways.. it could be because of that..